# Adding an overtime column to a Google Sheets template that includes the overtime rate in the total

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use this template to log bi-weekly hours. 
It is almost perfect except that there is no column for overtime hours.

How would I add an overtime hours logging column that would add the overtime hours and add them at a different rate?

For example this template allows for setting a pay rate. If the original rate is $35 per hour but overtime hours are 1.5X the rate how can I log the overtime and have them reflected in the total at the higher rate?

https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AmyTdQOsv2IydGhWUnlWbjZFUkxPWGg4cWs5a1QxY0E&mode=public

Answer (score 1):

Only Template Owners can update their templates. You could create a spreadsheet based in that template, then publish a new version of the template (be sure to give the proper attribution) or just create a copy of the modified spreadsheet for your own use.

Below there is a list of changes that you could consider to do in your own copy.

Regulars Hours (Column G)

```
=Max(0,(D:D-C:C)+(F:F-E:E)-8/24)
```

Overtime Hours (Insert column to the right of Column G, new Column H). To insert a new column select the Column G, then right click over the selected area and select `Insert Column to the right`

```
=Max(0,(D:D-C:C)+(F:F-E:E)-8/24)
```

Hourly Rate, Cell H26

```
=G26*1.5
```

Cell J25

```
=INT(H25)*24+HOUR(H25)+MINUTE(H25)/60
```

Cell I27 (Total Amount Due)

```
=sum(G27:H27)
```

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPre6YpyTNb5udvESRTWXCpPOkpNuaokWoNIXzbfJJg/edit?usp=sharing)